# Async task versus service to download data

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-download-manager

I want to know which is better to download files, async task or service?

My app has eight buttons, which one starts one direfferent download (which download has ~10MB). When the user clicks on one button or more to download data is better to use async task or service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In any case you should use `AsyncTask` because even service runs in the main (GUI) thread where no networking should be done. Whether to run the `AsyncTask` in a service or an activity depends on whether you want that download to continue in background.

Comment: Thanks @StenSoft, so if the apps goes to background or the user change to another activity, async task stops?

Comment: No but without a service, the whole application can be killed by the system any time in background.

Comment: hmm know I understand what I have to use on which moment! So I'll use AsyncTask.

You solved my boubt, thanks StenSoft!!

Comment: `Service` runs in the UI thread but `IntentService` uses it's own thread. `IntentService` allows your download to continue even if the user has closed app, and `AsyncTask` are ideally used for short operation [according to offical documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Download operation can be long, for me it seems that using `IntentService` is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

all above answers have good points. but the life-cycle issue is the most important thing you should consider. for instance, let's say you use `asyncTask`. so the user starts downloading and suddenly he/she rotates the screen and because you tied the `asyncTask` life-cycle to `activity` another `asyncTask` operation will be kicked off and result in a compulsive 10mb download. so considering this you should use `service` and `asyncTask` together to maintain life-cycle issue and UI thread networking issue.

**update**: Intent-service is a better solution because it receives requests in its own thread and goes offline when it doesn't have anything to do

Answer (score 1):

**AsyncTask** -- `AsyncTask` manipulate threads and/or handlers, if you can do that better with `Looper` and stuff why bother? AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler, and it should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)**..** how can you tell in production mode whether is not gonna take long? probably bad network, slow network,jammed network, phone restarting - and all these will probably make your downloading either corrupt or unfinished.. i am a user of apps, and i get pissed when i waste bundle on nothing..

if you ask me, use

**Service**
--`Service`is made to run irrespective of what app/screen is visible and make if communicate with the UI if only it is available if not continue with download and save it, `AsyncTask` does not constitute a generic threading framework. always use threads, its cool, we all love it.